# Как совмещать message.text и message.contact.phone_number в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Proverka.phone, content_types=['contact'])
async def step1(msg:types.Contact, state: FSMContext,):
    if (msg.contact.phone_number or msg.text) in bonuses.keys():
        global text
        text=bonuses[msg.contact.phone_number or msg.text]
        await state.update_data(phone=msg.contact.phone_number)
        await msg.answer("Введите номер карты")
        await Proverka.code.set()
    else:
        await msg.answer("Нет такого номера.")
        await state.finish()
```

Как совмещать message.text и message.contact.phone_number в aiogram. Отправить в State либо номер  телефона который был взять из Contact, либо введенный в ручном режиме.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Где-то вот так
`@dp.message_handler(state=Proverka.phone, content_types=['contact', 'text']`
UPD
Так будет получше

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Proverka.phone, content_types=['contact', 'text'])
async def step1(msg: typing.Union[types.Contact, types.Message], state: FSMContext):
    contact = msg.contact.phone_number if msg.contact else msg.text
```

Comment: async def step1(msg:types.Contact,....   а сюда надо что ни будь добавить?